# How to deep copy in ruby without using marshal?

Tags: ruby

this is what my project says :- "You must implement deep copying of lists yourself, without
relying on Ruby constructs for marshalling and unmarshalling data structures"
How do you do that?

Comment: Read the docs about Object.dup and Object.clone. (Not the solution, just a start. This is not trivial IMO.)

Comment: Why have you tagged this as `ruby-on-rails-3` **and** `ruby-on-rails-4`? I don't think this has even got anything to do with `rails`?

Comment: However, you *can* look at the rails implementation for some inspiration on how to do this, although this does it via class extension, which you might want to avoid. Deep copying for **all** objects will get very tricky, but at least for some subset (e.g. maybe you just need to for arrays of arrays of strings) it's not too hard: https://apidock.com/rails/Array/deep_dup https://apidock.com/rails/Array/deep_dup https://apidock.com/rails/Object/duplicable%3F

Comment: ActiveSupport has it, that's part of Rails but can be used independently, or you can snip the method and patch it in to any code-base you like. You can also write your own as an exercise, if that's what this question is really about. Implement `Object#deep_dupo` as a wrapper around `Object#dup` and then specialize it for things like Hash or Array.